# ReactRouter: Capture part of path and specify a value to match at the same time

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a path in the format of `/somePath/:name` where the `:name` needs to be one of the known strings. I read that the Route component supports an array of URLs to match, so it's easy to generate a list of supported paths, but doing so takes away the convenient of automatically capturing the part of the path.

For example, I currently have a Route component defined like this below.

```
<Route exact path={SomeKnownNames.map(n => `/somePath/${n}`)} component={SomeRoute} />} />
```

This should work, but I cannot access the value in `props.match.params` in the Route component anymore. Is there a way to achieve this without manually parsing the URL?

Let me add that I do NOT want to match if the value of `:name` is not in the known strings.

I'm using react-router-dom v5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, this works:

```
<Route exact path={SomeKnownNames.map(n => `/somePath/:name(${n})`)} component={SomeRoute} />} />
```

i.e. If you do `/somePath/:name(foo)`, then it matches `/somePath/foo`, and `foo` is captured in `props.match.params.name` in the route component.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried doing this:

```
path={SomeKnownNames.map(n => `/somePath/:${n}`)}
```

Adding the `:` allows the names to be treated as params. Try it out, let me know if that is unrelated. I may need more information to better answer your question.

Also, try to use the useParams() hook from React Router. What does it show in your component?

Comment: That wouldn't work. Since the name of the captured path is the actual name I'm trying to capture, I would need know that name beforehand...

Answer (score 0):

Update: path-to-regexp was [removed](https://reactrouterdotcom.fly.dev/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#note-on-route-path-patterns) from React V6, so this answer is obsolete.

React Router uses the path-to-regexp library, which allows you to provide your own regex for a parameter. See https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp/tree/v1.7.0#custom-match-parameters.

For example, if you want to match `/somePath/foo`, `/somePath/bar`, and `/somePath/baz`, and have `match.params` contain `myParam: "foo"`, `myParam: "bar"`, or `myParam: "baz"`, use this pattern:

```
<Route 
  exact
  path="/somePath/:myParam(foo|bar|baz)"
  component={SomeRoute} 
/>
```